# Mathematica PDE solving

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica and have never solved a PDE before. I tried to follow a textbook to get equation 4, but got something different with Mathematica (I got $(4\pi Dt)^{1/2}$ instead of $(4\pi Dt)^{3/2}$). May I ask why I got the wrong answer and how can I fix that? Thank you so much!

Textbook:

[image]

What I got:

[image]

Comment: Depends if the book is using $r \in \mathbb{R}$ or $r = (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. If it's the former then there is a typo in the book. If its the latter then the book is correct and you have not put the full set of coordinates into Mathematica. See the wiki on the [heat kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions).